# Detect if the caret is at the end of a line in insert mode

Tags: vim

I made this [pull request](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/pull/53) on the `vim-markdown` plugin by Tim Pope. Everything works except that
there is one bug, and one missing feature. This question is about the bug.

But first let me describe briefly the pull request:

- It implements auto-lists
- When a user is in a markdown list, presses `<CR>`, depending on where the caret is on the line, a
  new list item might be added (or the line will be split if the caret is in the middle of a line)

The problem is that I can't manage to detect when the caret is at the end of the line. The closest I
could get was to add a new list item if the caret is on one of the last two characters. The problem
is that whatever I do, the when the caret is before or after the last character in insert mode, it
goes ON the last character in normal mode, so I can't manage to detect if the caret is before or
after the last character in insert mode.

I tried using different combinations of `col('.')`, `col('$')` and `len(getline('.'))` among other
things, but everything I tried produced the same results: I can't differentiate the before and after
positions of the caret when on the last character in insert mode.

So how can check if the caret is AFTER the last character of a line in insert mode please?

Comment: Please show some code. What are these "different combinations of `col()` etc." that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you exit insert mode with `<Esc>`, the cursor always moves left (unless at column 1), so that should be the only condition necessary. I use this function:

```
function! IsCursorAtEndOfNonEmptyLine()
    return col('.') == col('$') && col('.') != 1
endfunction
```

from a mapping like this:

```
inoremap <silent> <F9>   <C-\><C-O>:call Foo()<CR>
```

Comment: First of all `col('.')` is never equal to `col('$')` because `col('$')` is the last column + 1. So your code with never work. Also, if you inspect `col('.')` in insert mode when the cursor is before the last char and after the last char, the result is the same. So I need another way of detecting the position of the cursor in insert mode; the `col()` function seems to simulate a temporary return to normal mode, which is not ideal...

Comment: @AzizLight: I've added my invoking mapping; the trick probably is the `<C-\><C-O>`.

Comment: you're missing the point. I'm trying to verify if I'm on the end of the line and do something based on that in a vimscript function. I can get the correct column number with `call feedkeys("\<C-r>=col('.')\<CR>")` but `feedkeys()` only works AFTER the function returns. Using `feedkeys()` is the only way I can think of resolving this problem, but I need to find a way to force it to occur immediately. I'm experimenting with recursive functions now...

Comment: I solved my problem, I will post the solution as soon as I get home.

Comment: @AzizLight Have you made it home?

Comment: Verified that @IngoKarkat's answer is indeed correct. The trick is in the `<C-\><C-O>` which, according to `:h i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O`, is "like CTRL-O but doesn't move the cursor".

@RobertAudi, safe travels on your amazing one and a half year journey home!

Comment: @IngoKarkat Wow, I totally forgot about this question. I stopped working on that pull request a long time ago. According to the comments, your solution is working, so I'm going to mark your answer as accepted. Sorry it took that long!

Answer (score 0):

```
function! IsCursorAtEndOfLine()
  if(col('$') ==# 1)
    return 1
  else
    return (col('$') - col('.')) ==# 1
  endif
endfunction
```